# Optimise mysql union query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have written following query to retrieve set of data from two different set of tables.

```
`SELECT `chapter_id`, `chapter_title`, `actual_content_type`, `area_name`, `status`
FROM ((
      SELECT `css`.`chapter_id`, `css`.`chapter_title`, `a`.`name` AS 
      `area_name`, `css`.`content_status` AS `status`, `css`.`actual_content_type`
      FROM `dm_content_search_summary` `css`
      INNER JOIN `curriculum` `cu` ON css.curriculum_id=cu.id
      INNER JOIN `year` `y` ON css.year_id=y.id
      INNER JOIN `area` `a` ON y.area_id=a.id
      INNER JOIN `country` `cou` ON a.country_id=cou.id
    ) 
      UNION ALL (
       SELECT `cpx`.`category_id` AS `chapter_id`, `cat`.`name` AS 
            `chapter_title`, `a`.`name` AS `area_name`, `pa`.`status` AS 
            `status`, 'PROVE_IT' AS actual_content_type
       FROM `qbnk_published_assessment` `pa`
       INNER JOIN `qbnk_assessment` `ass` ON pa.assessment_id=ass.id
       INNER JOIN `qbnk_assessment_question_xref` `aq` ON 
                ass.id=aq.assessment_id
       INNER JOIN `qbnk_question` `q` ON aq.question_id=q.id
       INNER JOIN `qbnk_answer` `an` ON q.id=an.question_id
       INNER JOIN `qbnk_category_published_assessment_xref` `cpx` ON 
            pa.id=cpx.published_assessment_id
       INNER JOIN `category` `cat` ON cpx.category_id=cat.id
       INNER JOIN `course` `co` ON cat.course_id=co.id
       INNER JOIN `curriculum` `cu` ON co.curriculum_id=cu.id
       INNER JOIN `year` `y` ON cu.year_id = y.id
       INNER JOIN `area` `a` ON y.area_id=a.id
       INNER JOIN `country` `cou` ON a.country_id=cou.id
         GROUP BY `pa`.`assessment_id`
  )
) `0` ORDER BY `chapter_title``
```

Relationships between tables
Country-areas is 1:many, area-year is 1:many, area-curriculum is 1:many, course-curriculum is 1:many, course:category is 1:many,  dm_content_search_summary:curriculum is many:1

qbnk_published_assessment:qbnk_assessment is 1:1, qbnk_assessment:qbnk_question is many:many, qbnk_question:qbnk_answer is 1:many, qbnk_category_published_assessment_xref:qbnk_published_assessment is many:many

Currently it takes more than 17 seconds to retrieve data. Is there any way to improve this query?
The results of explain command as follows.

[image]

====================================Update=================================

There are filters which need to apply for this query. That's why I join set of tables. Filtering fields are cu.subject_id, cu.year_id, a.id, a.country_id and css.actual_content_type. 
And I have to apply conditional search terms in ass.name, q.description, an.label, qbnk_category_published_assessment_xref, css.chapter_content and css.content_title fields. User interface of this section as follows.

[image]

After applying search terms and filters for query as follows.

```
SELECT `chapter_id`, `chapter_title`, `actual_content_type`, `area_name`, 
`status`
 FROM ((
   SELECT `css`.`chapter_id`, `css`.`chapter_title`, `a`.`name` AS 
   `area_name`, `css`.`content_status` AS `status`, 
   `css`.`actual_content_type`
    FROM `country` `cou`
    INNER JOIN `area` `a` ON cou.id=a.country_id AND a.country_id=4
    INNER JOIN `year` `y` ON a.id=y.area_id AND a.id=19
    INNER JOIN `curriculum` `cu` ON y.id=cu.year_id
    INNER JOIN `dm_content_search_summary` `css` ON cu.id=css.curriculum_id 
    AND cu.year_id=41 AND cu.subject_id=2
    WHERE (((((`css`.`content_title` LIKE '%Summary%') OR 
    (`css`.`chapter_content` LIKE '%Summary%')) AND ((`css`.`content_title` 
    LIKE '%and text%') OR (`css`.`chapter_content` LIKE '%and text%'))) OR 
    (`css`.`content_title` LIKE '%or text%')) OR (`css`.`chapter_content` 
    LIKE '%or text%')) AND ((css.actual_content_type='READ_IT' AND 
    css.chapter_content NOT LIKE '%not text%' AND css.content_title NOT LIKE 
   '%not text%') OR (css.actual_content_type<>'READ_IT' AND 
   css.content_title NOT LIKE '%not text%'))) UNION (
   SELECT `cpx`.`category_id` AS `chapter_id`, `cat`.`name` AS 
   `chapter_title`, `a`.`name` AS `area_name`, `pa`.`status` AS `status`, 
   'PROVE_IT' AS actual_content_type
   FROM `qbnk_published_assessment` `pa`
   INNER JOIN `qbnk_assessment` `ass` ON pa.assessment_id=ass.id
   INNER JOIN `qbnk_assessment_question_xref` `aq` ON 
     ass.id=aq.assessment_id
   INNER JOIN `qbnk_question` `q` ON aq.question_id=q.id
   INNER JOIN `qbnk_answer` `an` ON q.id=an.question_id
   INNER JOIN `qbnk_category_published_assessment_xref` `cpx` ON 
    pa.id=cpx.published_assessment_id
   INNER JOIN `category` `cat` ON cpx.category_id=cat.id
   INNER JOIN `course` `co` ON cat.course_id=co.id
   INNER JOIN `curriculum` `cu` ON co.curriculum_id=cu.id AND cu.year_id=41 
    AND cu.subject_id=2
   INNER JOIN `year` `y` ON cu.year_id = y.id
   INNER JOIN `area` `a` ON y.area_id=a.id AND a.id=19
   INNER JOIN `country` `cou` ON a.country_id=cou.id AND a.country_id=4
   WHERE ((((((((
     (`ass`.`name` LIKE '%Summary%') 
     OR (`q`.`description` LIKE '%Summary%')) 
     OR (`an`.`label` LIKE '%Summary%')) 
     AND (`ass`.`name` LIKE '%and text%') 
     AND (`q`.`description` LIKE '%and text%') 
     AND (`an`.`label` LIKE '%and text%')) 
     OR (`ass`.`name` LIKE '%or text%')) 
     OR (`q`.`description` LIKE '%or text%'))
     OR (`an`.`label` LIKE '%or text%')) 
     OR (`ass`.`name` NOT LIKE '%not text%')) 
     OR (`q`.`description` NOT LIKE '%not text%')) 
    OR (`an`.`label` NOT LIKE '%not text%')
 GROUP BY `pa`.`assessment_id`)) `0`
 ORDER BY `chapter_title`
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the unioned parts separately to see if one is more problematic than the other? Also, `cpx` and `ass` both join to `pa` independently; if neither is 1:1 to `pa` you will be getting the cartesian product of the `pa`'a associated rows for each pa.

Comment: Yes. Second part takes more time than other one

Comment: @Uueerdo Updated relationships in question

Comment: You will be getting every question of an assessment combined with every xref of that assessment. Is that you intended result? Keep in mind 10 q's and 10 cpx's for a pa means 100 result rows for just that pa. It is unclear why you are joining `ass->aq->q->an` when none of their fields are in the result or used in the other join "branch" of the query. If you are doing that as a filter for "only pa with q", you may want to consider making that part a subquery used in a `WHERE pa.assessment_id IN (subquery)` instead, as it will prevent duplication of results.

Comment: Can the `curriculum`, `year`, `country`, `area` tables be joined to the result of the union? It looks like the sort of 2M rows that are from both sides of the union is the largest consumer of time. Try with `ORDER BY NULL` and see what time? What MySQL versrion?

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions. This always presages disaster. Start with something simpler and gradually build complexity. And see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The problem I have with MySQL (and MariaDB) is that I'm not able to understand the execution plan for any query that is not extremely simple. By definition execution plans are trees, but MySQL show them in flat form and hides their tree organization. Sigh.

Comment: Well first of all try to narrow down the performance issue by running both parts separately and measure them. If both are fast separately, then the `ORDER BY` is slow. Otherwise you'll find one slower than the other, and you can start improving them by adding smart indexes.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks for reply. I have updated final query and user interface for your reference

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the reply. I applied it. It reduced reasonable amount of time to execute the query.  My mysql version is 5.7.23.

Comment: Glad it was faster. Which one UNION outside subquery? or without `ORDER BY`? like @TheImpaler said, some realtime meansures with results would be good. [Query PROFILE])https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) might also help. Group by on the second subquery does an implicit `ORDER BY`, so add a `ORDER BY NULL` there.

Comment: @danblack I joined curriculum, year, country and area tables to the result of the union. And I removed order by check the time. It was reduced 100 milliseconds.

Comment: `OR` is bad; leading wildcard on `LIKE` is bad; `JOIN`+`GROUP BY` is bad; 2M rows in the result is bad.  Shall I continue?  Bluntly:  There is no hope.  Start over in the requirements.

Comment: Yes @RickJames. Those are bad. According to the requirement need to search on those  fields. Yes. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it practical to use a `FULLTEXT` index?  (It only handles "words", and has other limitations.)

Comment: Currently I don't have experience in FULLTEXT search. But I checked for that to apply fulltext. But not sure how to apply it here.  Currently I'm using Yii2 php framework for development.

Comment: @RickJames Are you continue?

Comment: @cha - I stick with my meager answer.  You (and/or the 'requirements') need to bend on something.

Comment: @RickJames Do you think can I improve performance if I use FULLTEXT in this query? Need to consider framework as well.